# Android app bundle generated APK size huge when containing .so files

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-app-bundle

I have a project that includes a couple of cpu architecture specific .so files - the biggest being the xwalk lib, which is 60MB for the v8a version and 37MB for the v7a version.

When we had split APK the arm-v7a app apk version would be around 38mb and the arm-v8a apk would be around 41mb, which makes sense - zipping the lib would result in 23MB and 20MB, respectively.

When using app bundles it seems that the generated APKs are not compressed at all. the 60MB and 37MB are added to the apk size almost unchanged, resulting in a 97MB apk for 64bit arm devices.

I get consistent result when using the bundletool to generate the apks for one specific device and when downloading from the internal app testing play store site which returns the apks also depending on the device.

Am I missng something here or are app bundles not the best option when containing .so files and one is better off using split APKs again?

Comment: Did you add `ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a"
        }` in build.gradle file.

Comment: @SilverskyTechnology yes. the issue not that the 32bit lib would end up in the 64bit apk, just that the generated apk seems to be an archive only zip and not compressed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What matters is not the **file size** of the APK, but the **download size** of your app and the **size on device** of your app.

When you build an App Bundle, by default Play will leave the native libraries (.so) uncompressed in the generated APKs. Although this leads to a bigger APK file, this results in:

- **Smaller downloads** for users because the compression over-the-wire can be more efficient,
- **Smaller app size on the device** because the Android platform can mmap the .so files directly into memory without having to extract them first into a directory (thus saving a copy of the uncompressed .so file on disk).

[bundletool](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/bundletool) actually provides a command `get-size` which estimates the download size for you. In practice, this the size is often even smaller when better compression algorithms can be applied, but this is a best effort by Play.

Here's a [video from Google I/O 2019](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rEuwVWpYBOY) where they explain the difference between the different types of size you can measure (at 15:55), and what Play does to help reduce the size of apps.

Hope that helps,

Comment: thanks for the info. A question though: is the Internal app sharing a representative measurement tool? While the bundletool will show the apk download size estimated with 59mb, downloading the app via internal app sharing link will give me a 103MB download.

Comment: No, no optimizations are performed for internal app sharing.

Comment: But all other testing tracks should have it.

Comment: Hey Pierre, since it seems like you're the lead engineer on this, I had a quick question:
Which size does `ia check` look at? When I run that, it gives a warning that my app is over the 4MB limit, but my download size is only 3.1 MB when I look at the APK's in the App Bundle.  The `bundle-tool get-size` command provides the 3.1 MB.  Just wondering, because I'm having issues with a 2MB .so file, and I'm wondering if I need to go through the hassle figuring out how to reduce it, or if the Download Size of that is what is actually taken into account as it relates to Instant Apps.